# How can I define how many spaces a TAB jumps in a XAML TextBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, tabs

When the user presses a **tab** in this textbox, the cursor jumps an equivalent of **8 spaces**.

**How can I change it so it jumps only 4 or 2?**

```
<TextBox
    Width="200"
    Height="200"
    Margin="0 0 10 0"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    AcceptsTab="True"
    Text="{Binding OutlineText}"/>
```

Comment: Edward, if I suggest a solution with replacing tabs with spaces, will it work for you?

Comment: I've never seen it done in XAML.  Only in the actual editors.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own TextBox control to give the desired affect:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        //Defaults to 4
        TabSize = 4;
    }

    public int TabSize
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            String tab = new String(' ', TabSize);
            int caretPosition = base.CaretIndex;
            base.Text = base.Text.Insert(caretPosition, tab);
            base.CaretIndex = caretPosition + TabSize + 1;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just use the following in your xaml:

```
<cc:MyTextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TabSize="10" x:Name="textBox"/>
```

See the following original answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0d267009-5480-4314-8929-d4f8d8687cfd

Comment: Quick comments: I think you want to remove the `+1` on `base.CaretIndex =`, I'd probably pull out the `String tab...` line and put it into the `TabSize` setter so you're DRY-er in execution, and **most importantly, if you don't add** `base.SelectedText = string.Empty;` for the first line after your `if` clause, **strange things will happen if someone, say, highlights a word and hits tab**, expecting the word to disappear and be replaced by the tab "character". Otherwise very nice!

Comment: (This won't work if you insert text from code with tab-characters: `\t`, for example if you paste a block of text.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Typography property of the TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.typography.aspx). Even though I could not immediately find anything about tab size in there, this is the property that affects the way the text is rendered by the TextBox so it might as well be the thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try a control that allows you to set the tab size. Maybe http://wpfsyntax.codeplex.com/
will do?

Comment: This control just replaces tabs by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the solution Jason provided is that modifying the Text will erase the undo stack.  An alternative solution is to use the Paste method.  In order to do this you first need to copy your tab string to the clipboard.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        //Defaults to 4
        TabSize = 4;
    }

    public int TabSize { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            var data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            var tab = new String(' ', TabSize);
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, tab);
            Paste();
            //put the original clipboard data back
            if (data != null)
            {
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any trouble with undo -- can you explain what you mean? Using Jason's idea, I'm able to ctrl-z beyond the "tab" insert.

Comment: @ruffin I wouldn't have noticed the issue myself if I hadn't started using a slower laptop. There are two issues: 1) Setting the text of the `TextBox` messes with the undo/redo history. If you undo immediately after tabbing, the change observed involves all of the text versus just the new whitespace. This unintentionally leads to slower performance when text is long. 2) If your computer is slow, a delay can occur between setting the text and caret index. If you tab before the caret index is set, a new tab is inserted in the wrong place and the caret isn't where it you expect it to be.