# How to set the tab character width in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I want to reduce the width of the tab character in a `TextBlock`. The tabs are the equivalent of about 8 characters. I want to reduce to approximately 4 spaces.

```
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock 
    { 
        Text = "Some text\r\n\tLine with tab.\r\n\tAnother line",
    };
```

What I see:

```
Some text  
        Line with tab.  
        Another line
```

What I want:

```
Some text  
    Line with tab.  
    Another line
```

Comment: the only option I see is to create a custom control. See this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325826/how-can-i-define-how-many-spaces-a-tab-jumps-in-a-xaml-textbox

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing each occurrence of `\t` with four (or a number of your choice) `spaces`?

This approach could be implemented by modifying the code to

```
textBlock.Text =  textBlock.Text.Replace("\t", "    ");
```